# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11,140,55) into shape (11,140,11)

Tags: python

I have initialized the output_array as output_array[140,140,55] with np.zeros

Now when I am assigning value into the array with line

```
output_array[x_i_low:x_i_high+1,:,:] = np.squeeze(np.swapaxes(batch_array[:,:,:,:,b_start:b_end+1],2,4))
```

I am getting this error,
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (11,140,55) into shape (11,140,11)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `np.reshape` changes the shape of an `numpy.ndarray`.
That is:
If the initial shape is, let's say (x, y, z), and x * y * z = A,
than any reshape you are allowed to apply, say into `arr.reshape((a,b))`, a * b must equal **A** as well. Re-check your initial shape.

**tip**: setting a shape -1 saves you the calculation of the dimension (like a complement for **A**). Might be useful.

**EDIT:**
`x_i_low:x_i_high+1` is 11, therefore `output_array[x_i_low:x_i_high+1,:,:]` should be **(11,140,55)**, so `np.squeeze(np.swapaxes(batch_array[:,:,:,:,b_start:b_end+1],2,4)).shape = (11,)`. Wrong assignment. Shape must match.

Comment: The initial shape of output_array is 140,140,11.